Avalonia Treeview Selected Command
I'm trying to get an event to fire when I select a node on a treeview. I'm using a button to capture the command. I've had some ChatGPT help to no avail :-(
       <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
       <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Item}">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding LinkId}" ToolTip.Tip="Click Me" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
               <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.NodePressedCommand, 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">^</Button>
           </StackPanel>
       </TreeDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

I'm using community MVVM my command looks like:
 [RelayCommand]
public void NodePressed()
{
    // Set breakpoint here
    Debug.WriteLine("Clicked");
}

I'm getting this message: Unable to resolve property or method of name 'NodePressedCommand' on type 'System.Object'
If I go like <Button Command="{Binding NodePressedCommand}">^</Button>this I get: Unable to resolve property or method of name 'NodePressedCommand' on type 'AvaloniaTreeview.Models.Node'
So how do I get to the AvaloniaTreeview.ViewModels.MainWindowViewMode.NodePressedCommand?
I'm a bit new to Avalonia, TIA

This was my workaround, I added a button and used reflection binding:
  <TreeView    
    x:Name="myTreeView"   
    Grid.Column="0"    
    ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">   
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>    
    <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Item}">    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LinkId}" ToolTip.Tip="Click Me" />   
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />   
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />    
    <!-- [https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/12719] 
    (https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/12719) -->    
    <Button Command="{ReflectionBinding 
             #myTreeView.DataContext.NodePressedCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding LinkId}">^</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    </TreeDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>

